# flask-debugtoolbar not showing

Tags: python, flask

I have installed flask-debugtoolbar for better debugging.

Followed the instructions [here](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage). I also restarted the server in hope to get it right.

Here is my code.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Figured it out.**

Added this line,

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<replace with a secret key>'
```

above

```
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
```

Just **Exactly** followed [this](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage).

Answer (score 4):

As it clearly stated in the documentation that you linked to, you have to enable debug mode in your app.

> The toolbar will automatically be injected into HTML responses when debug mode is on. In production, setting app.debug = False will disable the toolbar.

You also need to specify a `SECRET_KEY` to enable flask session cookies.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

# Ensure that debug mode is *on*
app.debug = True

# Enable flask session cookies
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'key'

toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)
```

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug="True")`

Already added this code.

Comment: @RahulParashar Should be `app.run(debug=True)`. Also you need a secret key defined.

Comment: Yes, secret key was defined just under the `toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)`. Just fixed that and it worked. Thanks though for quick response.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem, it occurs when on the first application you use simple string rather than `render_template()`, so debug toolbar extention could not find the **body** tag so it does not appear you only see your hello message.

possible solutions;

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<html><body>hello</body></html>"
```

or this is much better,

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the issue because I was setting debug = True AFTER the toolbar was initialized, gotta call it before.